# How to properly call a function from a private class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue with calling a function from another class.

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity()
{
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
   {...}
   fun myFunction()
   {...}
   private class myAdapter (...) : BaseAdapter(), ListAdapter {
      ...
      //some code
      ...
      myFunction(); // <- How should I call it properly?
   }
}
```

Because I'm getting this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

I tried calling it **MainActivity().myFunction()** but it does the same.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with calling a private function. The object reference you're using to call getApplicationInfo() is null. Post the code where you're calling that method and the full stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not calling such function. In **myFunction()** I have only two lines: `setContentView(R.layout.myLaout)` and `val x = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.myImage)` When I call my function from anywhere there are no problems and everything is working, when I am calling it from that private class, that's the error I get and the application crashes. I believe findViewById is the line that crashes, because layout shows up.

Comment: That's why you should post the full stacktrace and the actual code. Context can give a lot of information missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter should be an inner class. Otherwise, it can not access the properties of MainActivity.
It should be like this: inner class myAdapter (...)

It can solve your problem but do not implement this approach as it's against clean code and the open-closed principle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found what I was looking for. I need to call it like that:

`(context as MyActivity).myFunction()`

Comment: Yes. "context" is the one you are using inside your adapter. It can be named differently, as myContext or just context like in this case.
`private inner class A2_HOME_SHOWLIST(context: Context)`

Comment: It's an unsafe cast. It may cause a crash in your application.

Comment: @MaedeJalali then, what should the safe cast look like? Just making it as inner class and then just calling it?

Comment: Nope. The safe cast is like this: (context as? MyActivity)?.myFunction()
In this way, if casting fails for any reason, It won't cause a crash in your app; it just won't call your function. In addition, using a context like that is also a dangerous method. But yes, the safer approach is making it an inner class and the safest approach is passing your function to your adapter.

Comment: This will probably solve the issue but not the problem itself. If you give us the information needed, we can help you 1) understand why this is happening and 2) solve it more efficiently.